# Not able to recover from sql backup file getting error Invalid default value for delete_time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore mysql server from `file.sql`.

I am trying following command

`mysql -u root -p database_name<  file.sql`

`Enter password:`

After entering password I am getting following error

`ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 7183: Invalid default value for 'delete_time'`

How to resolve this problem and recover my database back to servermysql

Comment: Your SQL file has an error at line: 7183 `Invalid default value for 'delete_time'`

Comment: corrected it then also unable to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Solved by including following query in backup file

`SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`